# Convert datetime to float - OpenERP 7

Tags: python, odoo

I used a float field with widget "float_time" to display a time. How I can convert datetime to float to display correctly in the widget?.

I explain a little more my scenario,

I have a field field 'start_date' which is datetime, I want that in the event "on_change" I set the time value in another field of type float that has the widget "float_time".

```
 'start_date': fields.datetime('Fecha Inicio' , required = True),
 'h_inicio': fields.float('Hora inicio', help="Hora inicio" , required = True),
```

In view :

```
<field name="start_date" on_change="onchange_f_inicio(start_date)"/>
<field name="h_inicio" widget="float_time"/>
```

Method on_change

```
    def onchange_f_inicio(self, cr, uid, ids ,fecha_inicio):
        res = {'value':{}}
        fecha_ini = datetime.strptime(fecha_inicio, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

       user = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid)
       tz = pytz.timezone(user.tz) if user.tz else pytz.utc
       fecha_ini = pytz.utc.localize(fecha_ini).astimezone(tz)     # convert start in user's timezone           

        hora_inicio = "%s.%s" % (str(fecha_ini.hour) , str(fecha_ini.minute))       
        res['value']['h_inicio'] =  round(float(hora_inicio),1)

    return res
```

The only way that has worked is to convert the date 'start_date' in a string and then convert to a float to be the value returned by the method on_change.

This form does not think it's the best, if I can help create a better way to thank you.

thanks

Comment: Please follow the post guidelines! If you want people to take the time to answer your question, you need to put forth the effort to give them something to work with.

Comment: Sorry, I will generate a better question.

Comment: It looks like you're already well on your way, by the looks of the updated question!

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is good, except for one small bug:

```
hora_inicio = "%s.%s" % (str(fecha_ini.hour) , str(fecha_ini.minute))
```

should be

```
hora_inicio = "%s.%s" % (str(fecha_ini.hour) , str(fecha_ini.minute // 60))
```

so that 30 minutes = `0.5` (and not `0.3`)